# Reverse image search using Django

Tags: django, search, reverse, photo

I wanted to add image search in Django admin. Instead of search using name and id, i have to give an profile image and then search for all users with particular image in Django admin.

Comment: Ok. What have you tried already?

Comment: Actually I am thinking of using face recognition library..

Comment: But not get idea of implementing that on django admin

Comment: If you have any idea please help me

Comment: I don't know, but I googled it in 5 seconds: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CZLyTGCSlwg

Comment: Thank you..I already saw that video, I got the idea from there, but it's not a complete video

Comment: Hi how django admin can search for a user in the database using an uploaded image of a user.. please help me